# Create dynamic form field inside form with dynamic validation in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have this data

```
"data": [
            {
                "sno": 1,
                "name": "name",
                "nameLabel": "Name",
                "isRequired": 1,
                "maxLen": 50,
                "order": 1,

            },
            {
                "sno": 2,
                "name": "desc",
                "nameLabel": "Description",
                "isRequired": 1,
                "maxLen": 50,
                "order": 2,
            },
            ..
            ..
```

I have to create these fields dynamically in form and use dynamic validation. If `isRequired` is 1 then that field is required, `maxLen` also we have to validate.

Any solution Thanks

Comment: in case you need a lib: https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly

Answer (score 0):

**follow the below way :)**

```
for (const field of this.data) {
      let validators = [];
      if (field.isRequired) {
        validators.push(Validators.required);
      }
      if (field.maxLen) {
        validators.push(Validators.maxLength(field.maxLen));
      }
      this.form.addControl(field.name, this.fb.control('', validators));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks can you pls add view code also how will i render it

Answer (score 0):

**Your HTML should be like**

```
<form *ngIf="Data != null && Data.length > 0" [formGroup]="rForm">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-12">
    <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let control of rForm.value | keyvalue">
        <label for="">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" [formControlName]="control.key">
        <span *ngIf="form.get(control.key).errors?.required">Field is required</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Your typescript should be like**

```
for (const field of this.data) {
  let validators = [];
  if (field.isRequired) {
    validators.push(Validators.required);
  }

  if (field.maxLen) {
    validators.push(Validators.maxLength(field.maxLen));
  }

  this.form.addControl(field.name, this.fb.control('', validators));
}
```

Thanks!